# Retrieving multiple data from db and grouping them

Tags: sql, mysqli

I'm looking for a sql command solution for this problem.
I want to retrieve all the rows that have the same atribute and list them.
I've tried group by, but it merges the results into one row per chosen field.
I want to retrieve the multiple results to do something like, without making single queries for each 'color':

- black

  - nissan
  - toyota
- red

  - ferrari
- yellow

  - porsche
  - lambo

Comment: the below link can help you..
[enter link description here][1]


[enter link description here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451856/querying-based-on-a-set-of-named-attributes-values
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097266/basic-sql-selecting-the-same-column-multiple-times-in-one-query-when-each-occ

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, queries produce a rectangular result set, not a hierarchical one, but something like this would work:

```
SELECT Color, Make
FROM Cars
ORDER By Color, Make
```

Then when you *display* the results you can show the `Color` only when it changes.